# custom post type is taking main post category automatically how to remove that

Tags: wordpress

I have changed my default category in setting. When i made a new custom post type in wordpress, it works fine but it taking default category from previously made (main)post category. And also those categories i made later in custom post type is showing in (main)post category list. Can someone help me.

My code is below.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_portfolio' );
function create_posttype_portfolio() {
    register_post_type('portfolios',
    array(
    'description' => 'Portfolio custom post type',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Portfolios',
            'singular_name' => 'Portfolio',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Portfolio',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio',
            'edit' => 'Edit Portfolio',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio',
            'new_item' => 'New Portfolio',
            'view' => 'View Portfolios',
            'view_item' => 'View Portfolio',
            'search_items' => 'Search Portfolios',
            'not_found' => 'No Portfolios found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolios found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Portfolio',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','revisions','thumbnail','author','thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Portfolios', 'with_front' => false),
    )
);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking . can you be more clear ?

Comment: Wordpress having its post type. in that post i have made a category. and set that as default category in setting->writting->default category. when i made a custom post type, the default category is showing in my custom post type category list. and also when i am creating new categories in custom post type those are showing in the main post category list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem wholly , but I will try .

"Categories" is a built in taxonomy for wordpress posts.
In your code you are specifically declaring that you want them to appear in your CPT.

```
 'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
```

If you do not want them to appear just take that bit off .
If your meaning is that you want your "own category thingie" it is called custom taxonomy ,you need to [register your own taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and use it .

Comment: I don't want main categories in custom post type but i need categories in custom post type.

Comment: These "special CPT categories " are called ["custom taxonomies"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: I have done this using CPT. All coming perfectly. but posts are not categorizing. don't know where is the problem.

Comment: @Tuku I do not understand what it means not categorized. Maybe open a new question

Comment: Sorry for not updating. That was solved, what i have asked.
[link](https://sattuk.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/post-columns.png)
The post columns were not showing..